# paypal integration with .net application possibly a web service not a website

Tags: .net, paypal, integration

i wanted to know if it is possible to integrate the paypal soap api with a .net wpf application or wcf service....i keep reading stuff about people integrating paypal with websites...thats not what i need...has anyone done this here??? if so can someone recommend which api package i need to use from paypal...what kind of account needs to be setup....
heres the scenario...i am writing a cc server that processes credit card transactions...the customers will not have and should not be required to have a paypal account...they just present the credit card info and my app/service should be able to either do a single auth or do an entire batch depending on the situation...i am not the seller in this scenario...and reading the docs is confusing me even more as to what are the basic requirements in terms of merchant account setup and other api requirements...
if paypal is not ideal for this scenario is there any other option....keep in mind there is no notion of a shopping cart here....
thanks

Comment: Be sure you transmit any credit card information using a secured connection to your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a SOAP service, any website that integrates its functionality is just a GUI on top of code that's calling PayPal's webservices.

So, the short answer is yes, you should be able to call the service from any application, including your own SOA service interface.

Comment: Small note to that: only if you use Website Payments Pro or Payflow Pro, as only these products will allow you to process card payments directly by submitting the card number in an API call to PayPal.