# Integrate Paypal Express with VB WPF app

Tags: c#, vb.net, paypal, express-checkout

I am creating a desktop application, which will allow the user to manage/use virtualized applications.  Some of the applications I have written and would like to sell thee applications. Right now I have a button (per app) that will download the app, run the app, and output info. However I have no way of integrating payment  into the program right now.  My idea is to write a class that controls whether or not the virtual application has been paid for, in order to enable the user to download the virtual application I have built, in which there's no problem doing so.  Yet, I need to integrate Paypal Express CheckOut to the program.

Would the integration be as easy as settings up a button that is linked to my Express Check Out cart.?Then once payment is processed by Paypal, send a IPN to the application? The issue I am running into is that the IPN goes back to a hyperlink. So, maybe I create code that will query the payment process of the transaction, then if true allow user to download virtual app? Would that work? Examples or any guidance at all would be great!

Note: I am writing in VB, however any examples in C# work as well. I have found an example of how to get IPN in vb asp.net: https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623. My guess is that I can integrate this into a WPF Window as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060595/paypal-integration-with-net-application-possibly-a-web-service-not-a-website 
might be able to help you

Comment: Are you trying to build Express Checkout into a native Windows app or are you building a web-based checkout and delivering software after it's paid?

Comment: I guess I am not trying to build Express Checkout into native Windows App or web-based check out.  I am trying to send just the information needed to Paypal's website for the person to pay ON paypal's website. Example a user wants 50 credits and there id to identify them for IPN. Send that information via SOAP protocol. Then on the UI of the app their will be a timer or click event trigger to get IPN and then allow credits to user after verification.